# How do I obtain ranges of features from a Machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, feature-selection, feature-engineering

My problem is as follows, I will try to present it succinctly:

I have about 20k sample data with ~12 features and a label (true or false). I can easily use either a regression or a classification type algorithm to get an equation in which I can plug features and obtain a label with some certainty.

My problem however is that my goal is a bit different. I need to think of an algorithm in which I can plug the label (true or false) and generated possible ranges for each feature.

One way I thought of doing this is cluster the point based on features until they clusters predict the labels with, say , ~90-100% certainty and then pick the centroids and the points around them as my magical "features required to obtain label". But I'm sure there must be a better, more formal even, way of doing this.

Any recommendations or algorithms that can extract feature ranges from labels given a decent size training set. Any thoughts on interesting ways to approach the problem. Any recommended reading to help me on the subject. Any form of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you just compute the feature ranges in each class separately?

Comment: Assuming that there are n features => 1 label I could look at each feature and compute the range for which that particular features results in that particular label. But since we are talking about a combination of n features here, selecting randomly from within those ranges would not result in that 1 label

Comment: Took out self-doubt, you came to the right place, congrats.

Comment: Or to formulate it differently, lets say: y1^2 - y2*18 => label 1 (if < 0 ) or label 2 (if >  0). The possible value for y1 and y2 range from -infinity to infinity but selecting a certain y1 would influence the selection of y2 (especially if we had limitations to solve the problem... say chose y1 and y2 as small as possible). Unless by "computing features ranges in each class separately" you meant something else. In which case please explain, I'm not very good at understanding ml-specific lingo